# Partial sums of periodic sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

Let $a_i$,$b_i$ be two periodic real sequences with a period of $n$. For $k\leq n$, denote the $k$-length partial-sums starting at $j$ by $a[j:k],b[j:k]$, i.e:
$$a[j:k] = \sum_{i=j}^{j+k-1}a_i\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,b[j:k] = \sum_{i=j}^{j+k-1}b_i$$

It is given that:

1. In both sequences, the sum of an entire period is $0$:
   $$a[1:n] = b[1:n] = 0$$
2. For some $k<n$, the $k$-length partial-sums of $a$ and $b$ have the same sign, i.e, for every $i$, either:
   $$ a[i:k]<0 \text{   and   } b[i:k]<0 $$
   or:
   $$ a[i:k]>0 \text{   and   } b[i:k]>0 $$

I am trying to prove (or disprove) that, for every $l<n$, there exists some $j$ such that the $l$-length partial-sums of $a$ and $b$ starting at $j$ are both weakly negative, i.e:
$$ a[j:l]\leq 0 \text{   and   } b[j:l]\leq 0 $$

This is obviously true when $l=k$: since the sum of an entire period is 0, if $a$ has a positive $k$-length partial-sum, it must also have a negative $k$-length partial-sum, and this must be true for $b$ too. Is this is also true for $l\neq k$?

Comment: and when $a = b$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not hold generally. Consider the following $a$ and $b$ with period $5$ (i.e. $n = 5$):
$$
a = 5,\ \text{-}1,\ 2,\ \text{-}10,\ 4,\ 5,\ \text{-}1,\ 2,\ \text{-}10,\ 4,\ \cdots
$$
$$
b = 4,\ \text{-}10,\ 2,\ \text{-}1,\ 5,\ 4,\ \text{-}10,\ 2,\ \text{-}1,\ 5,\ \cdots
$$
Note that $k = 1$ in this example. When $l = 2$, you can not find any $i$ such that $a[i:2] \leq 0$ and $b[i: 2] \leq 0$ hold at the same time.